How to add a gaps (slugs?) of specified time (interval) between clips in Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 with subsequent ability to modify time of these gaps?
Please help with Subject!
It is necessary to insert gaps (by blank clips or whatever) between video clips on timeline with specified time of gap (e.g. 3 sec) with ability to modify all inserted gaps to another time (e.g. 5 sec) in the future not by one by one manually.
Thank you in advance!
